# Accessing Gruntfile properties

Tags: gruntjs

I`m using grunt-string-replace to add the pkg.version value (defined in grunt.initConfig) to a css file name, to avoid caching when version changed. I also added a function in order to remove the dots from the version string. The result filename looks like this: style.css?013

Can i use the initConfig pkg.version value inside my replacement function instead of reading it again from the package file?

This is my string-replace configuration:

```
"string-replace": {
  dist: {
    files: {
      "dist/test.html": "dist/test.html"
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [{
        pattern: '#pkgversion#',
        replacement: function(){var p=grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'); return p.version.replace(/\./g ,'');},
      }]
    }
  },
},
```

Comment: Probably not as `function` create a new scope and is probably not called with an overwritten `this`. You could ask the Grunt plugin author for this functionality though; or send a PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [grunt.config.get](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/grunt.config#gruntconfigget) method.

For example:

```js
replacement: function(){
    return grunt.config.get('pkg').version.replace(/\./g ,'');
}
```